UK refugee travel documents
Can I go with my blue 1951 Geneva UK refugee travel document to Amsterdam and then from Amsterdam to Belgium?

Inputting dummy data regarding your trip into IATA indicates the answer is No for Belgium.
You can confirm the result by entering the real details using the link above. For ‘nationality’ scroll down to select ‘Stateless/Refugee’.
